# What's the difference between Blob objects and File objects in JS?

Tags: javascript, object

As said from the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob):

> The Blob object represents a blob, which is a file-like object of immutable, raw data; they can be read as text or binary data, or converted into a ReadableStream so its methods can be used for processing the data.

I also know that a File object inherits some of the properties of a Blob and it can be used pretty much everywhere that Blob can. But, if File can be used in the same context as Blob, how should I choose between them? Are there some cases that one is preferable from another?

Comment: There are blobs that arent files.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As said on the very page you linked:

> The `File` interface is based on `Blob`, inheriting blob functionality and expanding it to support files on the user's system.

The [`File` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) show that in addition to the blob properties, files also do have a `lastModified` date, a `name`, and possibly a path. It also states that

> `File` objects are generally retrieved from a `FileList` object returned as a result of a user selecting files using the `<input>` element [or] from a drag and drop operation's `DataTransfer` object

Whenever you can actually *choose* which one to use, that means you are constructing them yourself. In contrast to the [`Blob` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob), the [`File`  constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) takes a non-optional *name* argument. So whenever you're constructing something that you'd give a file name to, use `File`.